# Is there a Java/PHP bridge?

Tags: java, php

I have created a program but i need to get a java program to run a php script with some arguments and then get the php script to send some arguments to the Java program. I know this question has been asked a lot of times but it seems like the only answer i can get is that php can do this but java cant but there must be a way to do it. Right?

Comment: Never used it, but might be worth a look:
http://quercus.caucho.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can run PHP from the command line:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php
```

This should enable your Java application to run it, and capture it's return values.

Comment: I think it works but i really don't know a lot of php code so can you tell me how i can output the variables?

Comment: You can use return() for that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php